# grass GIS + spyder python script error

Tags: grass-gis, osgeo4w, grass.script, grass-7.2, pygrass

I'm getting crazy with grass gis and python. I want to call a grass function from an external python script (using spyder for instance).

I've installed QGIS + GRASS with the OSGeo4W64 installation suite (Desktop Express installation mode).

**My code is the following:**

I've specivied which line is working and which is not in the code:

```
import os
import sys

GISBASE = os.environ['GISBASE'] = 'C:\\OSGeo4W64\\apps\\grass\\grass-7.2.2' 
#GRASS_PYTHON = os.environ['GRASS_PYTHON'] = os.path.join(GISBASE,'extrabin','python.exe')
#PYTHONHOME = os.environ['PYTHONHOME'] = os.path.join(GISBASE,'Python27')
#GRASS_PROJSHARE = os.environ['GRASS_PROJSHARE'] = os.path.join(GISBASE,'share','proj')

#os.environ['PATH']+=os.pathsep +os.path.join(GISBASE,'extrabin')
os.environ['PATH']+=os.pathsep +os.path.join(GISBASE,'bin')
os.environ['PATH']+=os.pathsep +os.path.join(GISBASE,'lib')
LD_LIBRARY_PATH= os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = os.path.join(GISBASE,'lib')

os.environ['PATH']+=os.pathsep +"C:\\OSGeo4W64\\bin"

gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "grassdata")

location = "lacLeman"
mapset = "PERMANENT"

grass_pydir = os.path.join(GISBASE, "etc", "python")
sys.path.append(grass_pydir)


import grass.script as gscript
import grass.script.setup as gsetup
#this line works
rcfile = gsetup.init(GISBASE, gisdb, location, mapset)

## this line works
print(gscript.read_command('r.info',map='elevation',flags='g'))
## this line doesn't (that's what I want ultimately to do)
#gscript.run_command('r.horizon', elevation='elevation',step=1,coordinate=(512102.844311,148320.733533))
## this line doesn't work 
gscript.read_command('g.region', flags='p')
```

**My Output Errors:**

I got two successive windows error (see screenshot below):

[image: Entry point error for spatialite.dll]

[image: Entry point error for gdal202.dll]

Additionally I code an error in my Ipython shell:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 45: ordinal not in range(128)

But I think this error is just due to the errors mentioned above.

What did I miss?

I'm running on windows 10.

Comment: Check that the bitness of your libraries are matching; that Python, GRASS and QGIS all are 64-bit or 32-bit.  GRASS cannot find the function name in the library it is accessing. 32/64 bit programs usually cannot see the address of a function in another non-compatible library even though the library can be seen.

Comment: In addition, please consider to use GRASS GIS 7.4 available from the "Advanced" tab in OSGeo4W. It will soon be released, hence it then also shows up in the "Express" installation - here just FYI since you report troubles with the older 7.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the description of the error caused by **sqlite3.dll** here: [WinGRASS errors](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WinGRASS_errors).

Having tried renaming all **sqlite3.dll** files, at least this error is temporarily fixed.

However, the error due to **spatialite.dll** still remains an issue.